# MapReduce fundamentals

Tags: hadoop

1) `
      map(nr, txt)

```
 words = split (txt, ' ')
 for(i=0; i< |words| - 1; i++)
    emit(words[i]+' '+words[i+1], 1)

reduce(key, vals)
s=0
for v : vals
    s += v
if(s = 5)
     emit(key,s)`
```

2)   `map(nr, txt)

```
  words = split (txt, ' ')
  for(i=0; i < |words|; i++)
      emit(txt, length(words[i]))

  reduce(key, vals)
   s=0
   c=0
  for v : vals
      s += v
      c += 1
      r = s/c
 emit(key,r)`
```

I am new to MapReduce and when I am not able to understand if the "if condition in the code(1) will ever satisfy"

Q1 We need to determine what this MapReduce function do in both the code?
Could you please give any input on the above question.

Comment: Well, what's the input data?

Comment: @cricket_007: Thanks for the response. The  data is not given. This is just piece of code and we have to interpret what it exactly does( acc. to MapReduce technique). eg if there is text which has repeated words so we have to apply MapReduce function to take out the number of repeated words. This is my understanding I am not sure If I'm right but yes this is what I understood after studying MapReduce

Answer (score 0):

The first block of code emits all bigrams that appear more than 5 times. The reducer if condition satisfies if a pair of adjacent words exists at least 5 times

The second block emits every word of the input text with its length. It attempts to calculate the average length of each word, but since a reducer only sees a single key, then that calculation wouldn't do anything (seeing `"foo"` 1000 times still has a length of 3)